# Hiding Next and Previous buttons when First or Last items are active

Tags: javascript, jquery, hide, show, show-hide

I am having an issue hiding previous/next buttons for first/last items. I'm trying to hide the previous button on the first and hide the next button on the last. The current item has the class "active".

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container content">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-3 lefty">
            <div id="left-nav">
                <ul>
                    <li><a class="nav-button" href="#1">Link 1</a></li>
                    <li><a class="nav-button" href="#2">Link 2</a></li>
                    <li><a class="nav-button active" href="#3">Link 3</a></li>
                    <li><a class="nav-button" href="#4">Link 4</a></li>
                    <li><a class="nav-button" href="#5">Link 5</a></li>
                    <li><a class="nav-button" href="#6">Link 6</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-9 righty">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed accumsan efficitur nunc, ut suscipit nisl. Phasellus vitae tellus a nunc feugiat commodo eget ac lorem. Vivamus dolor nulla, tempor a vulputate at, auctor ac ex. Praesent vestibulum lorem vitae lectus fringilla, vitae aliquet velit consequat. Mauris erat urna, dictum ut aliquam at, accumsan eget leo. Cras vel egestas arcu, quis scelerisque libero. Pellentesque vulputate varius scelerisque. Proin elementum urna vitae enim tincidunt, et commodo massa sagittis.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed accumsan efficitur nunc, ut suscipit nisl. Phasellus vitae tellus a nunc feugiat commodo eget ac lorem. Vivamus dolor nulla, tempor a vulputate at, auctor ac ex. Praesent vestibulum lorem vitae lectus fringilla, vitae aliquet velit consequat. Mauris erat urna, dictum ut aliquam at, accumsan eget leo. Cras vel egestas arcu, quis scelerisque libero. Pellentesque vulputate varius scelerisque. Proin elementum urna vitae enim tincidunt, et commodo massa sagittis.</p>

            <div class="bottom-links">
                <a class="prev-button" href="#">Left</a>
                <a class="next-button" href="#">Right</a>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Working jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.next-button').click(function () {
        var $el = $('#left-nav li a.active').removeClass('active'),
            $next = $el.parent().next();

        if ($next.length === 0) $next = $('#left-nav li:first');

        $next.find('a.nav-button').addClass('active');

        // Added window.location.href to follow the selected links href
        window.location.href = $next.find('a.nav-button').attr('href');

    });


    $('.prev-button').click(function () {
        var $el = $('#left-nav li a.active').removeClass('active'),
            $prev = $el.parent().prev();

        if ($prev.length == 0) $prev = $('#left-nav li:last');

        $prev.find('a.nav-button').addClass('active');

        // Added window.location.href to follow the selected links href
        window.location.href = $prev.find('a.nav-button').attr('href');

    });
});
```

**My Attempt:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if($('.nav-button').eq(-1).is(':not(.active)')){
        $('.next-button').show();
    }
    else {
        $('next-button').hide();
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    if($('.nav-button').eq(1).is(':not(.active)')){
        $('.prev-button').show();
    }
    else {
        $('prev-button').hide();
});
```

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/jameelmoses/uo17qc94/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I just added a couple of conditions to hide and show the next/prev buttons

```
               //Bottom links
   $(document).ready(function() {
       $("#prev-button").text("link 2");
       $("#next-button").text("link 4");
       $('#next-button').click(function() {
           if ($("a.nav-button.active")[0] == $(".nav-button")[$(".nav-button").length - 2]) {
               $("#next-button").hide()
           }
           $("#prev-button").show();
           var $el = $('#left-nav li a.active').removeClass('active'),
               $next = $el.parent().next();

           if ($next.length === 0) $next = $('#left-nav li:first');

           $next.find('a.nav-button').addClass('active');
           if ($next.prev().find('a.nav-button')[0].innerText != undefined) {
               $('#prev-button').text($next.prev().find('a.nav-button')[0].innerText);
           }
           if ($next.next().find('a.nav-button')[0].innerText != undefined) {
               $('#next-button').text($next.next().find('a.nav-button')[0].innerText);
           }

           // Added window.location.href to follow the selected links href
           window.location.href = $next.find('a.nav-button').attr('href');

       });


       $('#prev-button').click(function() {
           if ($("a.nav-button.active")[0] == $(".nav-button")[1]) {
               $("#prev-button").hide()
           }
           $("#next-button").show();
           var $el = $('#left-nav li a.active').removeClass('active'),
               $prev = $el.parent().prev();

           if ($prev.length == 0) $prev = $('#left-nav li:last');

           $prev.find('a.nav-button').addClass('active');
           if ($prev.next().find('a.nav-button')[0].innerText != undefined) {
               $('#next-button').text($prev.next().find('a.nav-button')[0].innerText);
           }
           if ($prev.prev().find('a.nav-button')[0].innerText != undefined) {
               $('#prev-button').text($prev.prev().find('a.nav-button')[0].innerText);
           }

           // Added window.location.href to follow the selected links href
           window.location.href = $prev.find('a.nav-button').attr('href');

       });
   });
```

Comment: Any idea how I could make the link text for the next and previous buttons be the same as the name in the left-hand nav instead of "next" and "previous"?

For example: if Link 3 was the active item, the previous button would say "Link 2" and the next button would say "Link 4" instead of "Next" and "Previous"

Comment: i edited the code to make it do this, but there might be a cleaner way to do this so you might want to play around with it

Comment: also i just added some formatting to make the code easier to read

Comment: I couldn't get that to work for me for some reason. I was able to solve my issue on the text. I'm 99% of the way there now.

The only issue I'm having is hiding the button onpageload if the first or last item are active.

Fiddle: [http://jsfiddle.net/jameelmoses/uo17qc94/10/](http://jsfiddle.net/jameelmoses/uo17qc94/10/)

Comment: Note on my solution for the text for the buttons: I don't need the text to change onclick because when clicking on a link in the left nav it will go to a new page.

Comment: if ($("a.nav-button.active")[0] == $(".nav-button")[0]) {
           $("#prev-button").hide()
    } 
This should work.

Answer (score 1):

This will toggle visibility of the previous and next buttons, based on whether the first or last `.nav-button` is active:

```
$('.prev-button, .next-button').click(function() {
  $('.prev-button').toggle($('.nav-button:first').is(':not(.active)'));
  $('.next-button').toggle($('.nav-button:last').is(':not(.active)'));
});
```

---

You can combine this code with your existing code like this:

```
$('.prev-button, .next-button').click(function() {
  var $el = $('#left-nav li a.active').removeClass('active'),
      $link = $(this).hasClass('prev-button') ? $el.parent().prev() : $el.parent().next();

  $link.find('a.nav-button').addClass('active');

  $('.prev-button')
    .toggle($('.nav-button:first').is(':not(.active)'))
    .html($link.prev().text());

  $('.next-button')
    .toggle($('.nav-button:last').is(':not(.active)'))
    .html($link.next().text());

  window.location.href = $link.find('a.nav-button').attr('href');
}).click();
```

This will also change the text of the buttons to match the link text.

**Snippet**

```js
//Bottom links
$(document).ready(function () {

  $('.prev-button, .next-button').click(function() {
    var $el = $('#left-nav li a.active').removeClass('active'),
        $link = $(this).hasClass('prev-button') ? $el.parent().prev() : $el.parent().next();

    $link.find('a.nav-button').addClass('active');

    $('.prev-button')
      .toggle($('.nav-button:first').is(':not(.active)'))
      .html($link.prev().text());
          
    $('.next-button')
      .toggle($('.nav-button:last').is(':not(.active)'))
      .html($link.next().text());
      
    window.location.href = $link.find('a.nav-button').attr('href');
  }).click();
    
});
```

```css
body { padding: 30px 0; font-family: Arial; }

a, a:hover { text-decoration: none; }

.lefty {
    padding: 0;
}

#left-nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #eee;
}

#left-nav ul li a, #left-nav ul li a:visited {
    padding: 8px 16px;
    display: block;
    background-color: lightgray;
    color: navy;
}

#left-nav ul li a.active, #left-nav ul li a:hover, #left-nav ul li a:active {
    border-left: 4px solid orange;
    background-color: #eee;
    padding-left: 12px;
}

#left-nav ul li a.active {
    font-weight: bold;
}

.bottom-links a, .bottom-links a:visited {
    background-color: lightgray;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    color: navy;
    min-width: 60px;
    text-align: center;
}

.bottom-links a:hover, .bottom-links a:active {
    color: white;
    background-color: navy;
}

.prev-button {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 8%;
}

.next-button {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 8%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container content">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-3 lefty">
            <div id="left-nav">
                <ul>
                    <li><a class="nav-button" href="#1">Link 1</a></li>
                    <li><a class="nav-button" href="#2">Link 2</a></li>
                    <li><a class="nav-button active" href="#3">Link 3</a></li>
                    <li><a class="nav-button" href="#4">Link 4</a></li>
                    <li><a class="nav-button" href="#5">Link 5</a></li>
                    <li><a class="nav-button" href="#6">Link 6</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-9 righty">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed accumsan efficitur nunc, ut suscipit nisl. Phasellus vitae tellus a nunc feugiat commodo eget ac lorem. </p>

            <div class="bottom-links">
                <a class="prev-button" href="#">Left</a>
                <a class="next-button" href="#">Right</a>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I added a separate function so you could call it regardless of which nav was clicked (left or bottom, etc):

```
function setButtonDisplay(){
    var hidePrev = $('#left-nav li:first a.nav-button').hasClass('active'),
        hideNext = $('#left-nav li:last a.nav-button').hasClass('active');

    $('.prev-button')[hidePrev ? 'hide' : 'show']();
    $('.next-button')[hideNext ? 'hide' : 'show']();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try utilizing `onhashchange` `event`

```
var prev = $(".prev-button"), next = $(".next-button");
    window.onhashchange = function(e) {
    var active = $(".nav-button.active");
        if (active.index(".nav-button") === $(".nav-button").length -1) {
            next.hide(0);
            prev.show(0);
        } else {
          next.show(0);
            if (active.index(".nav-button") === 0) {
              prev.hide(0)
            }
        }
}
```